# Preserving matrix columns using Matlab brush/select data tool

Tags: matlab

I'm working with matrices in Matlab which have five columns and several million rows.  I'm interested in picking particular groups of this data.  Currently I'm doing this using plot3() and the brush/select data tool.

I plot the first three columns of the matrix as X,Y, Z and highlight the matrix region I'm interested in.  I then use the brush/select tool's "Create variable" tool to export that region as a new matrix.

The problem is that when I do that, the remaining two columns of the original, bigger matrix are dropped.  I understand why- they weren't plotted and hence the figure tool doesn't know about them.  I need all five columns of that subregion though in order to continue the processing pipeline.

I'm adding the appropriate 4th and 5th column values to the exported matrix using a horrible nested if loop approach- if columns 1, 2 and 3 match in both the original and exported matrix, attach columns 4/5 of the original matrix to the exported one.  It's bad design and agonizingly slow.  I know there has to be a Matlab function/trick for this- can anyone help?

Thanks!

This might help:

```
1.  I start with matrix 1 with columns X,Y,Z,A,B
2.  Using the brush/select tool, I create a new (subregion) matrix 2 with columns X,Y,Z
3.  I then loop through all members of matrix 2 against all members of matrix 1.  If X,Y,Z match for a pair of rows, I append A and B
from that row in matrix 1 to the appropriate row in matrix 2.
4.  I become very sad as this takes forever and shows my ignorance of Matlab.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly here is a simple way to do it:

Assuming you have a matrix like so: `M = [A B C D E]` where each letter is a Nx1 vector.

You select a range, this part is not really clear to me, but suppose you can create the following:

`idxA`,`idxB` and `idxC`, that are 1 if they are in the region and 0 otherwise.

Then you can simply use:

`M(idxA&idxB&idxC,:)`

and you will get the additional two columns as well.